# Linking rows between tables

Tags: mysql

I am very new to MySQL.  I'm sure this is answered somewhere else but seeing as I'm not sure exactly what it is I'm looking for it's hard to search for.  I am trying to link entries from a users table that they input data into, to another table that includes a field for comments to be stored with the original set of responses from the user.

Comment: Please provide your table structure and sample data.

Comment: For data Integrity you should evalute foreign key constrains. for query you should evalute  JOIN  and WHERE clause and of SQL Language. If you show yoy table structure is better..

Answer (score 0):

Your query must be something like this:

```
Select * from users_table as u
Left join comments_table as c ON u.id = c.user_id
/* Where _conditions_ */
```